# Need Tooltip on Listview column in XAML with text wrapping

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I am new to XAML and not familiar with the functions. I need a text wrapped tool tip on a single column(Message) in a listview to display the long texts in a concise format. This is my corrent code -

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Message}"/>
  </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But it displays the text of Message column for each cell of the entire listview. How do i make sure its displayed only on the required column and text wrap it? Please help.

Ok, so in response to my question, a tooltip can be wrapped and collapsed for null and empty values as per the following code:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
  <Setter Property="ToolTip">
   <Setter.Value >
     <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Path=Message}" Width ="200">
      <TextBlock.Style>
       <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
      </TextBlock.Style>
     </TextBlock>
    </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
  </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  What you need to narrow this tooltip down to just the specified column is a `key`.  This can't be used in `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`, but that's trivial.

**For your specific case try the following:**

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MessageColumnToolTip"  TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"> <!-- Defined Key -->
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Message}" Width="200">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Then an example usage:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="Auto"
    Header="Message">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Style="{StaticResource MessageColumnToolTip}" <!-- Defined Key -->
                Text="{Binding Path=Message}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

**Generic Approach**

Outside your specific case, if you wanted *all* cells to have a `ToolTip` and for all of them to wrap / behave this way, instead of copying this code for each column bound to a different property, the following generic approach works nicely:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"> <!-- Implied Key -->
        <Setter 
            Property="ToolTip"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Path=Text}"/>
        <Setter
            Property="TextTrimming"
            Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="200">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Then an example usage:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="Auto"
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Foo}" <!-- Implicitly uses Implied Key -->
    Header="Foo Column"/>
<GridViewColumn
    Width="Auto"
    Header="Bar Column">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" <!-- Implied Key -->
                Text="{Binding Path=Bar}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Hope this helps.